# Android: How to fit an Image perfectly in an ImageButton

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I just need to fit the image in the ImageButton but it always seems to be scaled down no matter what I do. Here's my layout. Kindly help me out here. I've found that scaleXY works for many but it doesn't seem to work here.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/front" >



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/babout"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="About"
        android:src="@drawable/about" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btshirt"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="T-Shirts"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shirt" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean that image shouldn't be stretched ?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly then

use

`android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

instead of

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```